# Path of light in Kerr metric?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, geodesics, kerr-metric

How can one find the trajectory of light in various direction in the [Kerr metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric)?
Just wondering if there are some classes of solutions, I don't need exact formula.

Are there different classes than in the [Schwarzschild metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric)?

Comment: [Edward Teo, "Spherical photon orbits around a Kerr black hole", Gen. Relativity and Gravitation **35** #11 pp1909-1926, 2003](http://www.physics.nus.edu.sg/~phyteoe/kerr/paper.pdf) is the best reference that I know of, and as it ways in the title it deals with spherical photon orbits which do not occur in the Schwarzschild spacetime. It's quite a technical paper, but it has lots of diagrams.

Comment: Have you also read http://www.scirp.org/journal/PaperDownload.aspx?paperID=25581 which is a paper I think may shed some (numerical) light on your problem, that of the consideration of light cones for the Kerr spacetime.